# Unable to add new Product after moving from AWS to local VM

Tags: magento2, product

I've just restore my magento 2 from AWS to my local VM for testing.

The site looks fine until I tried to Add a new product and would get the following error message as soon as I click the [Add Product].

> There has been an error processing your request The requested
>   component ("settings") is not found. Before using, you must add the
>   implementation. 
>   Error log record number: 582829183726

My site uses the Infortis Ultimo theme.

Please help.

Comment: Check your error number.

Comment: Sorry! Where can I find the error number?

Comment: Under `var` folder, `var/report`

Comment: I found a file with the name same as the log record number, "582829183726" but I opened it and don't know which is the error number. The file begins with... {"0":"The requested component (\"settings\") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/html\/magento2\/app\/code\/Magento\/Ui\/Model\/Manager.php(222): ...